# select with low-cardinality column with allow filtering throws an ERROR: No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators

Tags: database, indexing, cassandra, cql, nosql

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    type text,
    scope text,
    name text,
    version text,
    alias text,
    deleted boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((type, scope, name), version)
) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0
   AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
   AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
   AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
   AND comment = ''
   AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'min_threshold' : 4, 'max_threshold' : 32 }
   AND compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
   AND default_time_to_live = 0
   AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
   AND min_index_interval = 128
   AND max_index_interval = 2048;
CREATE INDEX test_alias ON test (alias);
CREATE INDEX test_type_index ON test (type);
```

This select doesn't work:

```
select * 
from test 
where type = 'type' 
    and scope='scope' 
    and name='name'
    and deleted = false 
allow filtering;
```

and gives me:

> No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided
>   operators: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException:
>   No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided
>   operators.

This select works:

```
select * 
from test 
where type = 'type' 
    and scope='scope' 
    and deleted = false 
allow filtering;
```

This select also works:

```
select * 
from test 
where type = 'type' 
    and scope='scope' 
    and name='name' 
allow filtering;
```

This select also works:

```
select * 
from test 
where type = 'type' 
    and scope='scope' 
    and name='name'
    and version='version' 
allow filtering;
```

Any idea? I don't want to create index on low-cardinality column and I don't understand why in some cases that query works (when I'm filtering through 2 fields from primary key and additionally field: deleted).

Cassandra version: 2.1.14

If I understood it right, there is no possibility to use condition on query with all keys inside composite partition key and another field together. But I didn't found any explanation of that...

Comment: What is your cassandra version ?

Comment: Pro-tip: Queries requiring ALLOW FILTERING and/or secondary indexes do not scale.  Build your tables to suit your queries, and this problem vanishes.

Comment: Cassandra version: 2.1.14

Answer (score 2):

Whatever needs to be queried on (part of a `WHERE` clause) needs to be indexed either as part of the primary key or a separate index.

For composite keys, the left most parts of the key need to be included to be able to search on the right most part of the key.

For example if a composite key is `(type, scope, name, deleted)` and want to query on `deleted` then need to supply `type, scope, name`. To query on `name` need to supply at least `type, scope` and so on.

Putting `deleted` as the second to last part of the key makes it search-able without the extra overhead an additional index would incur and is as efficient (or not) as deleted's cardinality is low.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
     type text,
     scope text,
     name text,
     version text,
     alias text,
     deleted boolean,
     PRIMARY KEY (type, scope, name, deleted, version)
 );
select *  from test
  where type = 'type'
      and scope='scope'
      and name='name'
      and deleted = false;

select *  from test
  where type = 'type'
  and scope='scope'
  and name='name'
  and version='version'
  and deleted in (true,false);
```

Note the removal of the double `and type='type'`, the inclusion of deleted with all possible values to be able to search on version and removal of allow filtering (does not perform well).

In general, make a schema to suit your queries. Think first 'how am I going to query this' to help you decide what to put as primary key and in what order. Forget relational database semantics, they do not apply.

Comment: "(...)Whatever needs to be queried on (part of a WHERE clause) needs to be indexed either as part of the primary key or a separate index.(...)" But as you saw on my example I don't have index on deleted column and second query works...

Comment: It 'works' as long as allow filtering is enabled, sure. The querying part is done on the indexed parts of the key, results of which are filtered on deleted. The query it self is not using deleted as part of its search.